# Hyperledger: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier <ID> has not been registered

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I was in charge of solving a problem in Hyperledger which consists of identity expiration, unfortunately i do not have much details about the network itself, i've tried to delete the card using:

```
composer card delete admin@network
```

And using import:

```
composer card import -f admin.card
```

Both card and bna are the in the same directory, but when doing so if i try to ping the network it shows the following error:

```
Hyperledger: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier <ID> has not been registered
```

I just need to recover this admin user without loosing or changing anything in the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check the listed cards on the network?

```
composer card list
```

for identity expiration and can't get access to your network, you can try this.

Set your machine datetime before the card expired.
go to your network directory ex. cd ~/example-network.
then request new identity:

```
composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -u admin -s adminpw newadmin
```

create new admin card:

```
composer card create -p config/connection.json -u newadmin -n example-network -c newadmin/admin-pub.pem -k newadmin/admin-priv.pem
```

import created card:

```
composer card import -f newadmin@example-network.card
```

extract created card (it's actually compressed file), i recommend to extract  into new directory called newadmin.

bind new identity:

```
composer identity bind -c oldadmin@example-network --participantId resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin --certificateFile newadmin/credentials/certificate
```

set back your machine datetime.
now you have access to your network again.

```
composer network ping -c newadmin@example-network
```

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There was a golden rule for hyperledger composer networks. Never let your identities expire. If you have (and it sounds like you have) then you will be locked out of your business network and there are no tools in hyperledger Composer to help you recover. Hyperledger Composer has been end of life for quite a while now so no one will be using it or developing it anymore.

Comment: The user is about to expire next month, what can i do to avoid this problem? I am aware that composer is no longer supported but the adoption of this tool is beyond my control, i need to prevent the network admin user to expire so that i can configure a proper hyperledger network after.

Comment: If the use has some sort of admin capabilities then maybe you can sort something like creating a new admin for example, but if not then there isn't anything you can do. As it is just fabric under the covers you could upgrade the composer chaincode business network to a pure fabric chaincode and remove composer altogether as it's the composer system that currently controls the access

Comment: Do i have to create a new card and bna or the old files will do?

Comment: I honestly can't remember now as I haven't used composer for so long. All I remember is that you have to be able to register a new identity with the business network in order for that identity to be able to do anything on the business network. If your unexpired user can't do that then it's a non starter. If your unexpired user can deploy business networks then maybe turning off all ACLs will then allow the unexpired user to register new identities. If it can't do that then you are locked out permanently from the business network.